# How to startup a tomcat server for a single specified context in ubuntu terminal without using eclipse?

Tags: tomcat

I don't know how to startup the server for a specific context. Is there any procedure or command for doing so.

Please somebody help me.Thanku in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are coming from starting tomcat from within Eclipse, where it seems to run only the specific web application that you are working with. But, in reality, Eclipse does not start Tomcat for a particular instance, but instead creates a separate root directory containing only the context that you are trying to run. If you look at "Run configurations" in Tomcat you can see that it sends something like this as VM arguments:

-Dcatalina.base=".......metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0" -Dcatalina.home="D:\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.29" -Dwtp.deploy=".........metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="D:\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\endorsed"

You could do similar thing from command line.